# AJAX send to php controller not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

The snippet shows my html and js.  In my php controller I just print_r($_POST) but I only see the form data for myName I can't figure out how to access zzz

UPDATE: I added some code to make sure the send request is complete.  However, if I don't submit the form the controller doesn't execute from just issuing the xhttp request.  I still can't get any js data into php.  I could create hidden inputs and fill those in from js and the submit but that seems ugly.  can someone help?

```js
function swagSend() {
  event.preventDefault();

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhttp.open("POST", "https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/php/send_email.php", true);
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      console.log(xhttp.responseText);
    }
  }

  var henry = "henry"
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send("zzz=" + henry);

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {

      document.getElementById("myForm").submit();

    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/php/send_email.php" method="POST" id='myForm'>

  <input type='text' name='myname'>
  <button type='submit' value='submit' onClick=swagSend();>Submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: where is `event` defined?

Comment: Just pointing out the flaw in your code.

Comment: it doesn't need to be defined

Comment: window.event is not the proper way to use the event object.

Comment: use jquery is lot elegant nd clean

Comment: trying to do this with just javascript

Comment: You are calling submit before the Ajax call completes. But not sure why you are making an Ajax call and also submitting the form to the same place.

Comment: how can I avoid that?

Comment: Wrapping it inside your `xhttp.onreadystatechange` callback... see: [onreadystatechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange)

Answer (score 0):

you should only send with xhttp.send and not additionally with document.getElementById("myForm").submit();

Comment: totally not helpful

Comment: sorry changed my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are making an Ajax call, there is no reason to submit the form. remove it.

If you want the form data to be submitted in the Ajax call, you need to read the form input values and build up the list yourself.

```js
function swagSend(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.open("POST", "https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/php/send_email.php", true);
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      console.log(xhttp.responseText);
    }
  }

  var henry = "henry"
  var name = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("myname").value)
  xhttp.send("zzz=" + henry + '&myname=' + name);
}
```

```html
<form action="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/php/send_email.php" method="POST" id='myForm'>

  <input type='text' name='myname' id='myname'>
  <button type='submit' value='submit' onClick="swagSend(event)">Submit</button>

</form>
```